# Delete row dynamically from angular material table

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I'm having trouble to delete row from the template. I was able to delete record from the database, but not from the template.

I've already try function with splice method, but I keep getting the error.

> this.articles.splice is not a function

`delete.component.ts`

```
deleteArticle(id: number) {
  return this.httpClient.delete(`${this.AUTH_SERVER}/api/v1/delete-article/${id}`).subscribe((res: any[]) => {
    console.log(res);
    this.listArticles();
    this.snackBar.open('Article deleted!', '', {
      duration: 2000
    });
  });
}
```

`delete.component.html`

```
<button mat-stroked-button color="warn" (click)="this.articleService.deleteArticle(article.id)">
  <i class="material-icons">
    delete_forever
   </i>
   Delete
</button>
```

Comment: I was able to achieve the goal simply by adding listArticles() function call to deleteArticle() function body. The logic was to reload the list after delete. The code above is the working code.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove/filter data sample:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  data: any[] = [];
  onFetch() {
    this.http
      .get("https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.data = res.data;
      });
  }
  onDelete(id: any) {
    this.http
      .delete("https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/delete/" + id)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.data = this.data.filter(x => x.id !== id);
      });
  }
}
```

Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-sun-nk69g

Comment: I've added `this.dataSource.articles = this.dataSource.articles.filter((x) => x.id !== id);` to delete function, just like in your example, and it work flawlessly. Basically, removed the row from an array directly from the DOM. No need for server request in case of `listArticles()` function. Am I understood this correctly?